# Regarding necessity of reflexivity in this problem.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I would like to solve the following problem:

> Let $L: B \rightarrow R$ be a bounded linear operator between Banach spaces, and $R$ be reflexive. Then $L$ maps weakly convergent sequences to weakly convergent sequences.

I have done the following: If $(x_n)$ converges weakly to $x$ in $B$, then for any $f \in R^*$, we get that $(f \circ L)x_n \rightarrow (f \circ L)x$; but since $f$ was arbitrary, $(Lx_n)$ converges weakly to $Lx$. Is there a hole in my argument? Or did I use reflexivity of $R$ without realizing it?

Comment: It is a general result: If $X,Y$ are normed spaces, $T\in B(X,Y)$ and $x_n\to x$ weakly, then $Tx_n\to Tx$ weakly.